# How do I play multiplayer on minecraft on the Xbox360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My little sister and I want to play minecraft together on the Xbox 360 E but when I try to connect her controller it won't show anything... Is it because I don't have a certain TV or do I need a wire or something?

Comment: You don't need anything special - You should be able to play spitscreen. Is the controller connecting to the console? Can she sign into a gamer profile?

Comment: Yes controler is connected

Comment: She cant sign in

Comment: I'd maybe try creating a new profile and try with that one, just to check if it's a problem with her existing one.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be connected to the tv/monitor via HDMI cable, some earlier model xb360 do not have this type of connection. However, later one do have both a vga and HDMI, connections